# Easy way to get rid of overlapping faces?

Tags: ambient-occlusion

I'm basically brand new to blender and finished the shape of my mesh. Here's the thing though: I did my modelling quick and dirty, partly due to time constraints and partially due to noob incompetence. Now I have a whole bunch of these overlaps in various places:
[image: It's worse than that...]
...and as a result it's screwed my AO bake, causing a bunch of these black and grey spots all over the model, like so:
[image: ...It's dead, Jim.]
Short of just clone-brushing my AO in Photoshop to some semblance of sense, is there a way of easily cleaning up these kind of overlaps? Some of them are pretty darned big.

Comment: My consistent experience with this has been that fixing stuff after the fact takes almost as much time as it would have doing it well from scratch, that is on top of the time it originally took to do it quick and dirty. All this without the satisfaction of well made work and often to get patchy end results

Answer (score 1):

There is no one universal *easy* way to fix bad geometry. In fact "clean" or "tidy" geometry usually means geometry that is specifically easy to work with, and "messy" or "bad" geometry is considered messy and bad because it is, like in this case, hard and time consuming to work with it. It is bad precisely because of situations like the one you are in now. When there are no issues like concave n-gons, inconsistent normals, overlapping or non-manifold geometry and everything is in quads, you can use various selection and modelling techniques based on the properties of the "tidy" topology. "Tidy" and "messy" geometry differs in a way that many modelling workflows just work with "tidy" geometry and do not work with "messy" geometry. That is why in many cases it might even be easier and faster to model something from the start than to attempt to fix it when it is modelled poorly. So if you want to get rid of the noob incompetence you mentioned, you should start thinking ahead when modelling and never model "quick and dirty" unless you know for sure you are going to get away with it in the future(which is often really hard to predict).